# pyqt Playing movie files in phonon player QT4.9

Tags: python, video, media-player, pyqt4, phonon

I'm definitely in need of your help guys.. As in really.
My laptop has been stolen and I didn't have a backup of my
pyqt phonon video player that I made a year ago. I forgot how and what to do to recreate it.
I only know some key things to do for it to work. So please help me out.

From what i can remember I need to

- Set backend capabilities (set phonon backend to windows media player?)
- Install the required codecs (which i dont have a copy of)
- Code the program (and sadly I forgot how to play a video)

If there's someone out there who have a working sample python videoplayer,
can you please share it with me?

I'm trying it right now and my sample doesn't work at all

```
from PyQt4.phonon import Phonon
        media_source = phonon.Phonon.MediaSource("C:\\Sample.avi")
        self.ui.videoPlayer.load(media_source)
        self.ui.videoPlayer.play()
```

Please help me. And thank you very much to you guys.

I'm using python 2.6 and qt version 4.9. Now I'm coding on a virtual box windows XP

EDIT:
got a following sample with this problem but..
having this error when loading a file.

> "The Operation Cannot Be Performed Because the Pins Are Not Connected"

This maybe because I'm using a virtual box in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 7):

Don't forget to `show()` the videoplayer. For the rest, in my experience Phonon often has trouble finding the codecs needed to play videos on Windows. Installing K-Lite codec pack might work in that situation.

Here's a self-contained example that does work for me (Windows Vista32, Python 2.6.5, PyQt 4.7.3).

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.phonon import Phonon
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
vp = Phonon.VideoPlayer()
media = Phonon.MediaSource('C:\\video.mp4')
vp.load(media)
vp.play()
vp.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Edit:**

Multiple people have recently commented that the above code no longer gives the desired behavior. I haven't worked with PyQt in ages, but I suspect that one of the updates might have changed Phonon functionality.

According to the commenters, `vp.show()` now needs to be called before `Phonon.MediaSource()`, i.e.:

```
...
vp = Phonon.VideoPlayer()
vp.show()
media = Phonon.MediaSource('C:\\video.mp4')
vp.load(media)
vp.play()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You should `show` the player before loading the media, otherwise it will show after it has played the movie. At least this is what happened in my case.

Comment: Also for me it not worked, `vp.show()` need to be before  `media = Phonon.MediaSource('C:\\video.mp4')` and also window for some reason is seems have size 0.

Comment: @mrgloom: I guess this may have changed in the past 4 years. Back in 2012, with PyQt 4.7, this worked fine. I'll update the answer.